# How to resize jscrollpane in jframe java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, layout-manager

i am new to java swing, currently i am developing an application using java swing, i am facing the problem is that when i populate my JList with JScrollPane it is displaying on my whole jframe.
code:

```
List<Element> parentElements = xmlUtil.getParentElements();
        String title = "License";
        JFrame f = new JFrame(title);



        String[] parentTags = new String[parentElements.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<parentElements.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(parentElements.get(i).getName());
            parentTags[i] = parentElements.get(i).getName();
        }

        JList list = new JList(parentTags);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,40)); 
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();

        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        f.setSize(900, 700);
        f.setVisible(true);
```

Output:[image: jscrollpaneoutput]

i want output like this so it can cover small area in jframe
[image]

Please tell me how to resize it ? as i am stuck into this problem from very long time.

Comment: there is a setPreferredSize(Dimension) method for most swing components. This should force a specific size for you. You can try calling it on the JScrollPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `JScrollPane` to a `JPanel` and then add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`:

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,40));
    contentPane.add(panel);
```

Then you can use the `setPreferredSize` method of the `JPanel` to resize it how you want.

Also consider using a good layout manager. I use a combination of two (primarily):

1. Netbeans' drag-and-drop WYSIWYG editor (Matisse)
2. [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) -- easily the best hand-written layout available. Some learning curve required (but less learning than the rest).

Comment: thanks its working...but it is displaying now mid of jframe can you please tell me how to set its position to the left size of jframe?

Comment: @Ahmad There are many ways. Refer to the second half of my answer for how to property position components. You need a layout manager. If you don't want to use Netbeans, try `MigLayout`

Comment: i am using netbeans, but my requirement is to position it programatically not by drag and drop...i am asking how to do it programmatically ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for use of good icons in a tree. 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 4) *"can you please tell me how..?"* See [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) but ..

Comment: .. a trick not stressed enough in the tutorial is that many UI's use more than one layout.  5) Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @Ahmad AT and I have given you enough info to try solving the positioning problem on your own. If after working through more of the problem on your own you have issues, then ask a new question.